# Does RubyMotion support integration of objective-c code?

Tags: objective-c, ios, rubymotion

There are a ton of libraries/pieces of code that have already been built in Objective-C can RubyMotion use these bits without rewriting them in Ruby?

Comment: My apologies if the rubymotion site mentions this - but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this. One is by vendoring your 3rd party code into the `vendor` directory and then using the `app.vendor_project` method in your `Rakefile`. See [Using 3rd Party Libraries](http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/guides/project-management/#_using_3rd_party_libraries) for an example.

Another option is using [Cocoapods](http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/articles/cocoapods/). With the `motion-cocoapods` Ruby gem, you can add any of the [libraries here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs) using something like this:

```
app.pods do
  dependency 'JSONKit'
end
```